# Efficient design to update another database whenever an entity gets updated in a application

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, architecture, orientdb

I have an application(App A) that uses orientdb(DB#1) as the database. Now we are developing another application(App B) that uses PostgreSQL(DB #2) as the database.

We now have a requirement wherein we need to list a few entities of app 'A' in app 'B' and also allow users to modify these entities in app B. All the changes that are performed on the entities of app 'A' in app 'B' should be reflected in DB #1. After a series of discussions internally with the team, we are convinced to migrate required entities data from db #1 to db #2 at once and later dynamically update DB #2 with records that get created/updated in db #1 and vice-versa.
Could someone please suggest efficient ways of keeping db #1 and db #2 in sync?

Note:

1. We are not interested in syncing db #1 and db #2 in real time, eventual consistency is fine for us.
2. Orientdb provides 2 kinds of hooks

   - Dynamic hooks( https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Dynamic-Hooks.html) which work at the schema level, not across databases.
   - Java hooks(https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Java-Hooks.html), which requires you to create a jar and place it in lib folder of orientdb.We ruled out this option since we have multiple instances of orientdb running in different regions which means every time we update a jar we need to update in all the instances of oriendb and debugging can be difficult since this jar runs as a subprocess inside oriendb.

Some of the approaches we considered:

1. Whenever a user creates/updates an entity in app 'A', create/update the respective record in db #1 and as soon we updated it in db # 1, in the application layer(java), push an equivalent Postgres sql query to update the record in db #2 into a persistent queue and process these messages asynchronously and vice-versa

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are thinking of a database level integration? Have you considered this synchronization at the application level through web services or messaging (jms?)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic pattern that emerges in a microservice architecture where each microservice app has its own database and then there is a need to pass that data to other services. There are multiple approaches:

1. App A directly updates the database used by App B.
2. App A calls a web service exposed by App B and then that web service updates the database used by App B.

Both of the above approaches result in tight coupling between App A and B which is not good. If the schema of database used by App B changes, the App A also needs to be updated in both the above approaches.

Instead the standard and recommended way of doing data integration between apps in the modern world is to use persistent queues such as Kafka. In this case whenever App A receives data updates, it pushes an event to the Kafka queue with the data and it doesn't care if App B receives it or not. App B subscribes to the queue and when it receives the events pushed by App A, it updates its own database.

With this approach, both apps are very loosely coupled. There is an overhead to maintain this Kafka infrastructure but in the long run, its worth it if the applications are going to get bigger. And if Kakfa is totally not an option, then approach 2 (via webservices) is better than approach 1 or other integration mechanisms.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for the quick and precise answer!!

Comment: As a follow-up question, let's say I am using Kafka and both the apps have subscribed both as a publisher and subscriber on different and respective topics so that both the applications publish their entity changes as events and parallelly consume the events (entity changes) to updated their DBs.So now how do i go about structuring this event so that my apps remain loosely coupled irrespective of schema changes? I thought a lot but couldn't figure out an efficient event structure(payload). Basically, I tried coming up with a common payload that just says what table changed with what values

Comment: Since I am including table names in my event payload, I will have to change my event processing logic in one or both the application when the schema changes. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: okay so loose coupling here means that there would not be an immediate need to deploy both apps if one of the app changes its schema. For example, there is a table with 5 columns in app A and let's say whenever any crud operation happens on that table, an event is pushed out so that app B can update its own DB. Now, let's say an additional column is added in that table in app A, in this case the Kafka event data will contain the data for this new column. However the consumer on the app B can safely ignore the additional data and thus nothing breaks. Later, app B can add that column, redeploy.

Comment: The idea is that due to this event driven architecture, nothing would break immediately. The producer app must keep the event data format backwards compatible (read protobuf backwards compatibility for more info) and the consumer app can later start consuming it whenever it is ready without immediately having to be taken down when there are changes in the producer app.

Comment: You mentioned that you are including table name in your event payload and I assume that you are also including column names and types. However the event payload format should not depend on DB schema. DB schema is the thing that is owned by the producer app and it should not be a part of integration payload because the integration payload can potentially contain data from various sources and not just the DB. Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using a solution based on "[change data capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture)" approach with an external tool like [debezium](https://debezium.io/).

The principle is to plug something to the bin logs of your database which will trigger events on data change, you will then implement listeners in charge of replicating the changes in the 2nd DB. This approach avoid to couple explicitly the different applications.